# Thin lens formula workout method (Query)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

[image]

In order to workout the method for establishing the formula of thin lens, my teacher says that the optical path is: 
    $PA + AQ = PS_1 + nS_1S_2 + S_2Q$    ($n$ is the refractive index of the lens)
Why is she multiplying $S_1S_2$ by $n$?

Also, she says that for spherical surface $S_1$, with centre of curvature $C_1$, we can write from geometry,
$h^2 = 2(S_1C_1 - OS_1) OS_1  $
How is she deriving this?

Comment: I guess she's using the paraxial approximation (small angles).

Comment: But how? Can you please show me the working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

> The optical path length for light travelling in a medium is defined as
>   the path length that will produce that same phase difference(or rather
>   contains same number of wavelengths) as light would when travelling in
>   vacuum.

Suppose the medium has a length(thickness) $t$.

A slab of the medium of thickness $t$ contains $\frac{t}{(\frac{\lambda}{\mu})}$ wavelengths which is equivalent to a slab of vacuum of length $\mu t$ which will contain $\frac{\mu t}{\lambda}=\frac{t}{(\frac{\lambda}{\mu})}$ wavelengths.

Therefore in order to find the **optical path length** in a medium we have to multiply by the refractive index.

2)Consider the following notation:

$x=OS_1$

$y=OC_1$

$h=OA$

$R=$radius of curvature of the first surface$=C_1S_1=C_1A$

Consider the Pythagoras' theorem in $\triangle AOC_1$,

$R^2=h^2+y^2$

Also we have $C_1S_1=R=C_1O+OS_1=x+y$

Using this in the above equation we get,

$x^2+2xy+y^2=y^2+h^2$

$2xy+x^2=h^2$

Since the lens is thin,$x<<y$ and so we can safely neglect the $x^2$ term,

$h^2=2xy$ which is exactly what we had to prove.